# Как в java swing изменить шрифт текста метода drawString (размер шрифтa и т.д. )

Tags: java, swing

К примеру, мне нужно вывести большими буквами "you Lose",
только пока текст почти не видно:

```
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.drawString("YOU LOSE", 200, 100);
```

Как можно изменить шрифт текста?

Comment: [`g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(40))`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30248879/5812238)